# Overlapped partitions in apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

While using custom partitioner in Apache Flink, I would like to assign some  elements of the dataset to more than one partition. Currently I try to duplicate those elements and assign each one to one cluster. I would like to know is there any ways to do so? If not what is efficient way of duplicating a subset of dataset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to generate overlapping partitions you first have to duplicate your elements. Given that you know which elements to duplicate this can be done with the `flatMap` operation. Since you want to assign duplicated elements to different partitions, it is best to assign the partition ID from within the `flatMap` operation. Based on this ID you can then apply the partitioning step.

Given an input data set `input: DataSet[IN]` you generate a duplicated data set `duplicated: DataSet[(Int, IN)]` which contains tuples of the original input elements and their corresponding partition ID. Afterwards you can apply the partitioning on the first tuple field.

```scala
val duplicatedDS: DataSet[(Int, IN)] = input.flatMap(x => duplicateElement(x))
val partitioned = duplicatedDS.partitionByHash(0)
```